# How to initialize GeoFire for Firestore Client Side?

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore, geofire, geofirestore

I'm looking to run GeoQueries client side in my app to query my Firestore DB and have reviewed the documentation here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries

However, it doesn't mention how to do this client side or how to initialize it. So I looked around I tried the following:

Adding a static .js file from the gitHub repo

```
<script src="/geofire-common.min.js></script>
```

And I get an error message that geofire is not defined.

I also tried using this link:

```
<script src="https://my-firebase-project.web.app/geofire-5.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

And still got the same error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get geoqueries for firestore client-side?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Putting

```
const geofire = require("geofire-common");
```

at the top of the code file where the queries are used works for me.